# Liferay announcements portlet hook

Tags: java, liferay, hook, portlet, liferay-6

I am trying to make a hook for the Liferay announcements portlet using the following code:

```
package com.ahc.hook.service.impl;

import com.liferay.portlet.announcements.*;

public class MyAnnouncementsEntryLocalServiceImpl
    extends AnnouncementsEntryLocalServiceBaseImpl {

    protected void validate(String title, String content, String url) {

        if (Validator.isNull(title)) {
            throw new EntryTitleException();
        }

        if (Validator.isNull(content)) {
            throw new EntryContentException();
        }

        if ((url.length() > 0) && !Validator.isUrl(url)) {
            throw new EntryURLException();
        }
    }

}
```

but I keep getting the following error:

```
[javac] Compiling 1 source file to /home/AHC/darryl.pinto/liferay/plugins/hooks/ahc-announcements-hook/docroot/WEB-INF/classes
[javac] /home/AHC/darryl.pinto/liferay/plugins/hooks/ahc-announcements-hook/docroot/WEB-INF/src/com/ahc/hook/service/impl/MyAnnouncementsEntryLocalServiceImpl.java:25: cannot find symbol
[javac] symbol: class AnnouncementsEntryLocalServiceBaseImpl extends AnnouncementsEntryLocalServiceBaseImpl {
[javac]               ^
```

I have a feeling I'm missing something for the extends section but I can't figure out what

I'm using Liferay 6.0.5

Anyone got any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *LocalServiceBaseImpl is not available to any hook as it's part of the implementation. Instead, what you want is to inherit from a *Wrapper. See the [documentation for overriding a service](https://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.0/development/-/ai/overriding-a-portal-service) on what to do. This also contains some reasoning and explanation what's available to you in the classloader your implementation is loaded in.